# VS code - code helper and backus-Naur form

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am learning VS Code and I do not understand the hints it is giving me while I code. Is this the Bakhus-Naur form?

[image]

The hint that VS Code gives is nothing like it is in the official documentation:

[image]

Does anyone know what this `log(message?: any, ...optionalParams: any(): void)` means? Or where can I find guide to decypher this?

Comment: `message?` means that it's optional. `any` means it can be of any type (string, number etc.). `...` means that you can pass as much parameters as you want.

Comment: So after the `:` there is always a type of the object?

Comment: Yes. It's a convention from typescript - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html

Comment: @MoshFeu: It's much older than TypeScript. E.g. both Mozilla's abandoned JavaScript 2 and the abandoned ECMAScript 4 had optional type annotations with the exact same syntax. The ML family of languages, Haskell, Scala, Kotlin, etc. also have it. It goes all the way back to mathematical type theory, even before there were computers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio Code uses the [TypeScript Language Service for its ECMAScript editing experience](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/JavaScript-Language-Service-in-Visual-Studio). In other words, even when writing [ECMAScript](https://tc39.es/), Visual Studio Code treats it as (or more precisely, similar to) as [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/). It infers types for all expressions, variables, functions, parameters, properties, methods, etc. and performs [type checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-checking-javascript-files.html), overload resolution, and so on and so forth.

In order to do that successfully, it uses [TypeScript Type Declaration files](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html), both for the [ECMAScript standard library](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es2015.core.d.ts) and standard Web APIs (e.g. [WebWorker](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.webworker.d.ts), Canvas, XmlHTTPRequest, `window`, etc.; [here's the Type Declaration for the DOM, for example](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.dom.d.ts)), as well as for any libraries that you use in your code. (For third-party code, it uses [Automatic Type Acquisition](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/working-with-javascript#_typings-and-automatic-type-acquisition), where it either takes TypeScript Type Declaration files that are shipped inside the module, if the module provides them, from the `@types` NPM namespace, or the DefinitelyTyped project.) It also uses [type information from JSDoc type declarations](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-checking-javascript-files.html#jsdoc-types-are-used-for-type-information).

What you are seeing there, is just normal [TypeScript function declaration syntax](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#optional-and-default-parameters) which in this case I believe comes from the Type Declaration file for Node.js, which is published in the [`@types/node` NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/node) and written as part of the [DefinitelyTyped project](http://definitelytyped.org/).

You can find [the source code for this TypeScript Type Declaration file in `types/node/globals.d.ts`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/node/globals.d.ts#L57-L60):

> ```js
> /**
> * Prints to `stdout` with newline.
> */
> log(message?: any, ...optionalParams: any[]): void;
> ```

Which means (roughly):

- A method named `log` with
- an *optional parameter (`?`)* named `message` of type (`:`) `any` (meaning it could be anything) followed by
- a *rest parameter (`…`)* (i.e. an array that "slurps up" all remaining arguments) named `optionalParams` of type array of (`[]`) `any`,
- returning nothing (the return type is `void`)

Note that from the looks of it, the IntelliSense you are getting seems to be from the `@types/node` package and is for the [Node.js console](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_log_data_args):

> ## `console.log([data][, …args])`
>
> Added in: v0.1.100
>
> - `data` [*<any>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Data_types)
> - `…args` [*<any>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Data_types)
>
> Prints to `stdout` with newline. Multiple arguments can be passed, with the first used as the primary message and all additional used as substitution values similar to [`printf(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) (the arguments are all passed to [`util.format()`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_format_format_args)).
>
> ```js
> const count = 5;
> console.log('count: %d', count);
> // Prints: count: 5, to stdout
> console.log('count:', count);
> // Prints: count: 5, to stdout
> ```
>
> See [`util.format()`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_format_format_args) for more information.

Whereas the documentation screenshot you shared is definitely *not* for Node.js, but seems to be for some web browser. In particular, the first overload in the documentation screenshot you shared is *not* supported by Node.js according to the Node.js documentation (although it does actually work if you try it out).

It is not quite clear to me why Visual Studio Code would show you the Node.js type for a web project. That seems to be a bug.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation!